# iOS scrolling issue with forms

Tags: ios, angularjs, uiwebview

i am developing a mobile app for iOS using angularjs and Xcode v 6.2 using UIWebView using the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSURL *htmlFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]     
  pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];
 [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:htmlFile ]];

}
```

i used single view project

the issue is here

the user hit next until reach the last field  and hit done , the keyboard hide but the top part of the form can't be shown again unless keyboard showed again and click pervious to get to the first input